# how to write repeatedly numbers for 900 to 1000 with pyautogui

Tags: python, loops, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time

D = 900

for D in range(100):
    pag.write(D)
    pag.press("Enter")
    D += 1
```

i want it to type untill its get to 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyautogui as pag

D = 900

while D < 1001
    pag.typewrite(f"{D}")
    pag.press('Enter')
    D += 1
```

Int has to be string!